# ModelSim PE Student Edition 10.1c (STD_LOGIC error)

Tags: importerror, modelsim

I am trying to use STD_LOGIC in my VHDL code. It will not compile because the STD_LOGIC I am trying to use in the `port(.....)` section is not working. I know the problem is because I did not import the IEEE library. I tried to import it but I was not successful.

How to import the IEEE library properly to a VHDL program in ModelSim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To import the package that defines the std_logic type to a VHDL design, add the following two lines to the top of your VHDL file:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
```